# How insert SELECT in Join codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to add sub-query select in `$this->join()` in Codeigniter?
I tried do this such:

```
 $this->db->join('stocks AS stn', 
 'stn.stocksIdMF = (SELECT b.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser FROM medicalfacilities AS b WHERE 
    b.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser = stn.stocksIdMF AND stn.stocksEndDate >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    ORDER BY stn.stocksId DESC LIMIT 1', 'LEFT');
```

**Full query:**

```
 $this->db->from('medicalfacilities');
        $this->db->join('users', 'users.idUsers = medicalfacilities.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser');
        $this->db->join('medicalfacilities_directions', 'medicalfacilities_directions.id_MF = medicalfacilities.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join('subscrubetousers su', 'su.SubscrubeToUsersIdNote = medicalfacilities.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser AND su.SubscrubeToUsersType = 9', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join('thematicspecialization', 'thematicspecialization.idSpecialization = medicalfacilities_directions.id_specialization', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join('evaluationinstitution ev', 'ev.evaluationinstitutionIdInst = medicalfacilities.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join('stocks', 'stocks.stocksIdMF = medicalfacilities.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser AND stocks.stocksEndDate >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join('commentstomedicalfacilities', 'commentstomedicalfacilities.CommentsToMedicalFacilitiesIdMedical = medicalfacilities.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join('medicalfacilities_type', 'medicalfacilities_type.idMF = medicalfacilities.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser');
        $this->db->join('typesmedicalfacilities', 'typesmedicalfacilities.type = medicalfacilities_type.type');
        $this->db->join('stocks AS stn', 'stn.stocksIdMF = (SELECT b.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser FROM medicalfacilities AS b WHERE b.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser = stn.stocksIdMF AND stn.stocksEndDate >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
        ORDER BY stn.stocksId DESC LIMIT 1)', 'LEFT', FALSE);
```

Last `JOIN` do wrong finish query.

Error is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'b.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser FROM medicalfacilities AS b WHERE b.MedicalFacilitiesI' at line 12
```

Comment: Its quite interesting. What error are you getting ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `FALSE` parameter to the end of your `->join()` like this:

```
$this->db->join('','','', FALSE)
```

Comment: Im not understanding what you mean. Can you run `$this->db->last_query();` and show us the query it builds?

Comment: Is not possible do `$this->db->last_query();` because query is not wrong. I can show query with error, but it so big string

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$this->db->join('stocks AS stn', 
 'stn.stocksIdMF = (SELECT b.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser FROM medicalfacilities AS b WHERE 
    b.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser = stn.stocksIdMF AND stn.stocksEndDate >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    ORDER BY stn.stocksId DESC LIMIT 1)', 'LEFT', FALSE);
```

Comment: It gives me error and wrong query: `LEFT JOIN stocks AS stn ON `stn`.`stocksIdMF` = (`SELECT` b.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser FROM medicalfacilities AS b WHERE WHERE `medicalfacilities`.`MedicalFacilitiesVI`